# <br/> and &nbsp; appearing in searched text

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I have a modal where users can add notes via a `textarea`. They are able to type multiple spaces and line breaks into the text area. After adding a note it appears immediately in the notes modal. An input field above allows the user to search the newly created notes. A highlight span wraps the text that was searched on.

I'm using regex to create the `&nbsp;` and `<br/>` so formatting from the textarea shows in the displayed note.

**The issue is that the `&nbsp;` and `<br/>` that are created appear in the hightlighted search results.**

#### Highlight Filter

```
.filter('highlighted', function($sce) {
    return function (note, phrase) {
      if (phrase) {
        //phrase = phrase.replace(/^\&nbsp\;|<br?\>*/gi, "").replace().trim("");
        note = note.replace(new RegExp('(' + phrase + ')', 'gim'), '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>');
      }
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(note);
    };
  })
```

#### Note Service

```
noteService.getNotes(idPart)
  .success(function(result) {
    $scope.notes = result.notes;
    if ($scope.notes) {
      result.notes.forEach(function addDates(notes) {
        notes.dateSort = moment(notes.timestamp).format('MMMM D YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
        notes.timestamp = moment(notes.timestamp).format('MMM D, YYYY');
        notes.notes_raw = notes.note;
        var carriage = /\n/g,
          space = /\s/g,
          findCarriage = notes.note.replace(carriage, "<br/>"),
          newstr = findCarriage.replace(space, "&nbsp;");
        notes.note = newstr;
      });
    }
    console.log('success');
  })
  .error(function() {
    $scope.$emit('alert', 'danger', 'Failed to retrieve notes');
    console.log("failure");
    $modalInstance.close($scope.$parent.$id);
  });
```

#### HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search.notes" placeholder="Search" aria-describedby="sizing-addon3" />

<ul class="notes-list">
    <li ng-repeat="note in notes | filter:search.notes | orderBy:'-dateSort'" class="note well">
      <span><strong ng-bind-html="note.timestamp | highlighted:search.notes"></strong> <em ng-bind-html="note.user | highlighted:search.notes"></em></span>
      <p ng-bind-html="note.note | highlighted:search.notes"></p>
     </li>
 </ul>

 <textarea autofocus class="form-control" rows="3" id="new-note" ng-model="data.note" maxlength="140" placeholder="Character limit 140 characters" required ng-focus="characterCount();"></textarea>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-info" ng-disabled="partNotes.$invalid" ng-click="add()
          ">Add</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-link" ng-click="clear()" formnovalidate>Clear</button>
```

Comment: Try using `/&nbsp;|<br\s*\/>/gi`.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work `phrase = phrase.replace(/&nbsp;|<br\s*\/>/gi, "").trim("");`

Comment: The try you gave also strips the formatting of the nbsp and br, which I'd like to keep

Comment: Note that I referred to ^\&nbsp\;|<br?\>*`. It has several issues, but I guess it has nothingto do with yoyur problem described here.

Comment: Is there some reason you're avoiding the <pre> tag which should be able to handle displaying the extra spaces and line breaks?

Comment: @Robharrisaz no reason. I'll fiddle with that element but I'm not sure why it would fix the issue. :/

Comment: @Robharrisaz  The issue is that the html that is used for formatting is showing up as `&nbsp;` and `<br/>` in the highlighted note. I don't want them to. `pre` didn't help.

Comment: now I'm having using when search when `!` is typed 1st :(